# How to send mail without using email-credentials via nodemailer npm in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendmail, nodemailer, mail-server

I know how to send mail using nodemailer but I am using email credentials of that, but I don't want to use that. Is there any other method of sending mails.

**My nodemailer code snippet is**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Not the movie transporter!
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: 'vikaskohli@email.com', // Your email id
          pass: 'password' // Your password
      }
  });

module.exports =
{
   sendEmail: function sendMail(varhtml,vartext, varsubject,varfrom, varfrom_name,varto, varto_name, reply_to_email ) {


       //setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
       var mailOptions = {
            from: varfrom_name, // sender address
          // to: ['vikaskohli@email.com','vikaskohli1@email.com'], // list of receivers
               // to: ['vikaskohli@email.com,vikaskohli1@email.com'], // list of receivers
               // to: 'vikaskohli@email.com','vikaskohli1@email.com', // list of receivers
           to: varto, // list of receivers
           subject: varsubject, // Subject line
           text: vartext, // plaintext body
           html: varhtml // html body
       };


       console.log(mailOptions);

       // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
           if (error) {
               return console.log(error);
           }else{
             return console.log(info);
           }
       });


   }

}
```

In the above code, also I don't change my sender name. If I want to send from other mail like

> vikaskohli3@gmail.com

but it automatically send from that mail for which I have use credentials here

> vikaskohli@email.com

Also I tried using sendmail npm, they don't need any credentials but it send mail in the spam folder

**My sendmail code snippet**

```
 var sendmail = require('sendmail')({silent: true})
  sendmail({
    from: 'vikaskohli@email.com',
    to: 'vikaskohli@email.com,vikaskohli1@email.com',
    subject: varsubject, // Subject line
    html: varhtml,
    attachments: [
    ]
  }, function (err, reply) {
    console.log(err && err.stack)
    console.dir(reply)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use sendmail like your bottom code, and it works fine for me. Perhaps the reason it's going to spam is because your settings in the email provider. Most likely the email you chose as sender (@email.com) seems like a spam to that service provider or your settings.

Comment: I am using authing authenticated domain with valid email but it still sending in a spam

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI have you tried whitelisting the IP address?

Try this to check report on your mail server http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/

I will test mine later.